# How to deselect radio button in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to deselect my Radio Buttons that I have in my program in JFrame,it exists some method to deselect all Radio Buttons trough one button called Clean ? This button will clean the radion buttons and the texts that have.

The code of Action Performed that will make clean all thinks :

```
JButton btnClean = new JButton("Clean");
        btnClean.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            }
        });
        btnClean.setBounds(208, 184, 126, 28);
        contentPane.add(btnClean);
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually JRadioButtons are grouped together in a ButtonGroup object, a logical object that allows only one JRadioButton to be selected at a time. What you will want to do is to call `clearSelection()` on this ButtonGroup object.

As an aside, you look to be using a `null` layout with your GUI. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BunchOButtons extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] RADIO_TEXTS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    private ButtonGroup weekDayBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    public BunchOButtons() {
        // JRadioButtons love being held in JPanels that use GridLayout
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        radioPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Week Days"));
        for (String radioText : RADIO_TEXTS) {
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(radioText); // create radiobtn
            radioButton.setActionCommand(radioText); // set its action command text
            weekDayBtnGroup.add(radioButton); // add to ButtonGroup
            radioPanel.add(radioButton);   // add to a GridLayout-using JPanel
        }

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Selection") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ButtonModel model = weekDayBtnGroup.getSelection();
                if (model != null) {
                    // if something is selected
                    System.out.println(model.getActionCommand());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No weekday selected");
                }
            }
        }));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear Selection") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                weekDayBtnGroup.clearSelection();
            }
        }));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BunchOButtons mainPanel = new BunchOButtons();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BunchOButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't found the ButtonGroup object in Components,where he can be found ? PS : I am new to the JFrame,I am doing course of Programming,but we was using only Java in JOptionPane.

Comment: @Novatec javax.swingx.ButtonGroup

Comment: @Novatec: as Mad states -- look in the API for ButtonGroup. Also a Google on `Java ButtonGroup Tutorial` first hit: [The ButtonGroup Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html). Also look at the code example above.

Answer (score 1):

As your `JFrame` may contain many `JRadioButton` components arbitrarily nested in the frame's layout, you may need to recurse down the component hierarchy using [`Container.getComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) and check if each component is an instanceof `JRadioButton`, in which case you should cast and `.setSelected(false)` it, or a `Container`, in which case you should continue the recursion. To obtain the `JFrame`'s top-level container, use `JFrame.getContentPane`.

To illustrate this approach with a simple example (containing an implementation of the `Clean` method requested by the OP):

```
public class FrameWithRadios extends JFrame {

    public FrameWithRadios() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
        panelCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        JRadioButton rb11 = new JRadioButton("Option 1.1");
        JRadioButton rb12 = new JRadioButton("Option 1.2");
        JRadioButton rb13 = new JRadioButton("Option 1.3");

        JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel();
        panelLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        panelLeft.add(rb11);
        panelLeft.add(rb12);
        panelLeft.add(rb13);

        panelCenter.add(panelLeft);

        JRadioButton rb21 = new JRadioButton("Option 2.1");
        JRadioButton rb22 = new JRadioButton("Option 2.2");
        JRadioButton rb23 = new JRadioButton("Option 2.3");

        JPanel panelRight = new JPanel();
        panelRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        panelRight.add(rb21);
        panelRight.add(rb22);
        panelRight.add(rb23);

        panelCenter.add(panelRight);

        JButton bClean = new JButton("Clean");
        bClean.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               clean(getContentPane());
           }
        });
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(bClean);

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        cp.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    protected void clean(Component comp) {
        if (comp instanceof JRadioButton) {
            ((JRadioButton) comp).setSelected(false);
        }
        else if (comp instanceof Container) {
            for (Component child: ((Container) comp).getComponents()) {
                clean(child);
            };
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrameWithRadios frame = new FrameWithRadios();
        frame.setSize(320, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Of course, as others have suggested, you'll most likely *want* to assign the management of your radio buttons' selection state to a `ButtonGroup` and use the `ButtonGroup.clearSelection` method to deselect everything (the above will not work for radio buttons in a `ButtonGroup`).

Comment: BurpttinGroup isn't a component or container and aren't added to the UI. Instead, it managers a group of buttons

Comment: My bad. I meant to say check if each individual component is a `JRadioButton` and deselect it with `.setSelected(false)`.

Comment: However, this works only if the `JRadioButton` components are not in any `ButtonGroup`.

Comment: Thanks man your kind of code helped me a lot,I was just needing that,not making a ButtonGroup.